# Searching on the go for bluetooth devices and have access on them

Tags: bluetooth, mobile-phone

I am thinking of a situation that i have a smartphone in my hands and use bluetooth to search nearby devices(all sorts of)... Is there a approach to get into a device either from a bluetooth way or some other way without notifying a user.

I think of this because for example i can shutdoen a network machine(meant through an IP access). Can i give the same command to a mobile device which has a bluetooth or some other way to get into and have access to it to make a restart or open an __ app???

Dont get mad at me...its just a thought and hope that something is there in this world.

Cheers!!!!

Answer (score 0):

May be some sort of spyware app will do it. But there must be that software(some sort of spyware) installed both in the device sending command and the command receiver.

Comment: "May Be" i am also stuck in that.. but in realtime i have seen softwares but i need working apps, currently i have a symbian phone up with me but can go for android also for a share... but i need a hardcore application so that i can satisfy checking the stregnth of it realtime...

Comment: You can check for softwares @ [BlueToothJacking](http://www.bluejackingtools.com/)

Comment: @GOK That will be impossible to do anything without notifying user, unless you have hacked it and planted a virus, trojan, or spyware inside it. And the software or virus can be varied on the OS platform of the device.